# Accents over Bars in LaTeX

Tags: accents

Neither combination of the following two elements renders a felicitous result: `\={\'o}` ~ `\'{\=o}`. In the first case the bar comes over the accent; in the second the accent appears right before the barred letter. How can I make a grave or acute accent over a barred letter?

Comment: Is this for IPA content? Can we see your font setup?

Comment: It is for IPA. The font is the same as below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`ipa`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ipa) package allows

```
\documentclass{standalone}\usepackage{ipa}
\begin{document}
\texttt{ipa} \diatop[{\diatop[\'|\=]}|o]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The [`tipa`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tipa) package has `\textacutemacron`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}
\texttt{tipa} \textacutemacron{o}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And the [`phonetic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/phonetic) package has the following to offer (which seems to not work under T1 font encoding):

```
\documentclass{standalone}\usepackage{phonetic}
\begin{document}
\texttt{phonetic} \acbar{\'}{o}
\end{document}
```

[image]